# Erro ao deserializar uma List Json em Java

Tags: java, json

É o seguinte, recebo uma lista no formato JSON. Porém parece que há algum tipo de inconformidade na maneira que o JSON é montado. Segue o código...
Tenho uma classe cliente que está da seguinte maneira.

```
public final class Cliente {

    private Integer Id;
    private String nome;
    private String cpf;
    private String endereco;
    //Com os Getters and Setters
}
```

A classe com o método Main está assim..

```
package br.com.pecapreco.pecas;

import java.util.List;

import com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.GenericType;
import com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource;
import br.com.pecapreco.model.Cliente;

public class Programa {

    public List<Cliente> listar() {

        Client client = Client.create();
        WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://localhost:8080/prjRestful3/cliente/");
        return webResource.path("listarTodos").get(new GenericType<List<Cliente>>() {
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Programa pg = new Programa();
        List<Cliente> list = pg.listar();
        for (Cliente cliente : list) {

            System.out.println(cliente.getNome());
        }
    }
}
```

E o seguinte erro é exibido no console:

> Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not deserialize to type interface java.util.List
>       at com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter.readFrom(GensonJsonConverter.java:127)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:634)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientResponse.getEntity(ClientResponse.java:604)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:698)
>       at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.get(WebResource.java:198)
>       at br.com.pecapreco.pecas.Programa.listar(Programa.java:16)
>       at br.com.pecapreco.pecas.Programa.main(Programa.java:22)
>   Caused by: com.owlike.genson.JsonBindingException: Could not deserialize to type interface java.util.List
>       at com.owlike.genson.Genson.deserialize(Genson.java:384)
>       at com.owlike.genson.ext.jaxrs.GensonJsonConverter.readFrom(GensonJsonConverter.java:125)
>       ... 6 more
>   Caused by: com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonStreamException: Illegal character at row 0 and column 0 expected [ but read '{' !
>       at com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonReader.newWrongTokenException(JsonReader.java:942)
>       at com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonReader.begin(JsonReader.java:418)
>       at com.owlike.genson.stream.JsonReader.beginArray(JsonReader.java:149)
>       at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$CollectionConverter.deserialize(DefaultConverters.java:172)
>       at com.owlike.genson.convert.DefaultConverters$CollectionConverter.deserialize(DefaultConverters.java:159)
>       at com.owlike.genson.convert.NullConverterFactory$NullConverterWrapper.deserialize(NullConverterFactory.java:77)
>       at com.owlike.genson.Genson.deserialize(Genson.java:382)
>       ... 7 more

***EDIT 1:***

Esse é o Json que eu tô recebendo:

{"cliente":[{"cpf":"314-63-6517","endereco":"65 Dennis Trail","id":"42","nome":"Aigneis McTeer"},{"cpf":"836-24-5953","endereco":"21 Doe Crossing Court","id":"5","nome":"Aile Drabble"}]}

Comment: Faltou postar também o JSON que vem pela URL.

Answer (score 0):

O Json que montou não reflete a classe Cliente. No começo do Json indica que tem uma lista dentro da propriedade "cliente", fato que não acontece e "id" no Json é diferente de "Id" na classe. Tente passar o Json no seguinte formato:

```
    [{"cpf":"314-63-6517","endereco":"65 Dennis Trail","Id":42,"nome":"Aigneis McTeer"},
{"cpf":"836-24-5953","endereco":"21 Doe Crossing Court","Id":5,"nome":"Aile Drabble"}]
```